# How to make a toast message of JSON response in android?

Tags: php, android, json

- After click on delete button i want to show a delete message in toast in android application
- Can any one tell me the following code is right or i have to add something in it.

> Android Java code

```
private void delete(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.43.63/deletr.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                        JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (res.has("Deleted")) {
                        String aJsonString = res.getString("Deleted");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), aJsonString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("title",getCarEdit.getText().toString().trim());
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

> PHP code

```
 <?php
    include 'connection.php';

    global $connect;
    $id = $_POST["title"];


  $query = "DELETE FROM `products` WHERE title='$id'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

  if ($result) {

  echo json_encode("Deleted");
    }

    else{
       echo json_encode("Delete Failed");
    }
```

> php response
>   [PHP response after asigned some manual values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKhwC.png)

Comment: whats your problem? you need code verification or you face error?

Comment: Toast not visible in android application.

Comment: Values are deleting from database. but toast message not working or showing

Comment: @GirrajPancholi https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKhwC.png -Is this your response from API ??

Comment: yes, and i want to print that "Deleted" message in toast

Comment: @GirrajPancholi that means your response is in string. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Changes in your PHP file :

```
$success = array( 
        "output"=>"your data Deleted"); 
$error = array( 
        "output"=>"your data not Deleted"); 

    // Use json_encode() function 
    if($result){
      $json = json_encode($success); 
    }else{
      $json = json_encode($error);
    }
    // Display the output 
    echo($json); 
    //
    // check hear your result if else code

    Output like : {"output":"your data Deleted"}
```

and  in your android code :

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
      @Override
         public void onResponse(String response) {               
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("error",error.toString());
         }
      });
```

I hope it'll help you...!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know php but your android code is ok, we have use two ways to get api response .

**first** : simple use json paring

```
JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);
                if (res.has("Deleted")) {
                    String aJsonString = res.getString("Deleted");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), aJsonString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

**second** : assign whole api response to pojo class and get data from Pojo  class

**add this gradle**

```
First Step
```

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

> Second Step

copy response and create pojo class using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

> Third Step

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
 Response r = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Response.class);
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), r.getDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

In My case my pojo class name is Response

Answer (score 0):

As your response is already in string as you mentioned here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKhwC.png

First check your response with `Log.e()`;

```
    @Override public void onResponse(String response) {

                Log.e("response=="," "+response);
                try {
                       // Your response is already in String, so just past it in toast message.
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: @GirrajPancholi check this answer, hope it will helps you.